# React: Element type is invalid error when it shouldn't happen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following error when I try to use a component

`` Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `MemberSearchBar`. ``

I read other stack-question and it is about exporting it by default , i am already doing that.
I am importing the component like:

`import MemberSearchBar from './member-search-bar';` ( I am absolutely sure the import path is correct)

then I'm just using it, like `<MemberSearchBar />`

the code for the component is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
import { StyledSearchInput } from './member-search-bar.styles';

export default class MemberSearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value });
    debounce(this.state.searchText, 300);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <StyledSearchInput
          isInline
          isSmall
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone has any ideea why I get that?

Comment: where have you used `<MemberSearchBar />` in your code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import StyledSearchInput from './member-search-bar.styles';`?

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee in the render method of the file where I'm importing my component

Comment: Can you post code in file `member-search-bar` ? `styles and StyledSearchInput`

Comment: can you share that code?

Comment: @jdn the code from member-search-bar is the one in the post, the styledSearchInput is just a styled-component from the form components we buit. they work everywhere, so that's not the problem

Comment: Doesn't matter how confident *you* are that it works. We also need to be confident that it works otherwise we can't really answer

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the 'StyledSearchInput' component.

React cannot find a valid component in this case.

Either './member-search-bar.styles' path is wrong OR the component is wrongly constructed.

Also share the file with member-search-bar.